# python json use for parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing

The string is composed like below:

```
{resp_to={request=objects_download}|objects={object1={object_name=Name of object 1|objecttype=type1}|object2={object_name=Name of object 2|objecttype=type1}}|error=0}
```

How is the best way to extract all object names for all objects contained in objects?

I'm getting confused with json and it is driving me crazy to understand how it works.

Comment: That syntax is *not* JSON. I have no idea what syntax that is, though.

Comment: Many thanks Martijn, I tryed to parse it with python -mjson.tool and infact it gives me a 'No JSON object could be decoded'. The question is from your prospective how is the best way to get the object_name as a list ?

Comment: You can convert it to JSON, using some regex replacements (or something  like this: `str.replace('=', ':')` - but the second aproach is not a very good idea).

Comment: @MostafaR: There are no quotes present here, and we have no idea how this format handles unicode. Not a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, just a quick idea ;-)

Comment: @TonyManero: I'd use `pyparsing` to whip up a parser for that format, but it'll be based on educated guesses only. You have *nothing* else on what format we are looking at here?

Comment: @MostafaR I already tryed this but still doesn't work. 'No JSON object could be decoded'

Comment: @TonyManero As Martijn said it's not a very good idea, but if you want to try it, please paste your conversion result here.

Comment: The right solution would be find out who has written that string and ask for a formal description of that format and a parser for it. Standards are standards for a reason.

Comment: I tryed this substitution but in same cases doesn't worked `self.modOutput = re.sub(r'([^{}|=]+)',r'"\1"',self.modOutput)`
`self.modOutput = re.sub('[=]',':',self.modOutput)`
`self.modOutput = re.sub('[|]',',',self.modOutput)`

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the text using a recursive descent parser e.g., [`lepl`](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase, digits
from lepl import AnyBut, Delayed, Drop, Integer, Word

def Parser():
    # ABNF-ish grammar:
    #   object  = '{' pair *( '|' pair )  '}' # sequence of pairs inside {}
    #   pair    = key '=' value               # key, value separated by =
    #   value   = integer / string / object   # any of ..
    #   key     = [a-z_][a-z_0-9]* # regex syntax
    #   string  = [^{}=|]+         # regex syntax
    obj = Delayed() # forward declaration
    key = Word(lowercase + '_', lowercase + '_' + digits) # digit can't be 1st
    value = (Integer() >> int) | AnyBut('{}=|')[1:,...] | obj
    pair = key & Drop('=') & value > tuple # (key, value)
    obj += Drop('{') & pair[1:,Drop('|')]  & Drop('}') > dict
    return obj.get_parse()
```

Example:

```
import json

text = ("{resp_to={request=objects_download}|"
        "objects={object1={object_name=Name of object 1|objecttype=type1}"
        "|object2={object_name=Name of object 2|objecttype=type1}}|error=0}")
obj = Parser()(text)[0] # parse text into a dict
print(json.dumps(obj, indent=2)) # pretty print
```

Output:

```
{
  "resp_to": {
    "request": "objects_download"
  }, 
  "objects": {
    "object1": {
      "object_name": "Name of object 1", 
      "objecttype": "type1"
    }, 
    "object2": {
      "object_name": "Name of object 2", 
      "objecttype": "type1"
    }
  }, 
  "error": 0
}
```

Comment: this is good for this execple only but the output that i need to parse is varable for lenth and object.

Comment: @TonyManero: I don't understand. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15687013/edit) to include an example input where `Parser()` fails